# Test app version before publishing to production on Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app in production published on the Play Store with many active users.  I'm using in app purchase to process in-app purchases, so I need to release an update that is not released to users but only to 1 test user to be able to test if everything is ok before officially releasing to production.  Can I do this with closed Alpha?  What is the best practice for this?  I'm afraid to release and get released for all update users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely do it with a closed alpha, and it sounds like a good way of doing it.  There are ways to test in app purchases on debug releases, but even then I think doing a smoke test of the end to end process before updating all your users is generally a good idea.

Comment: Thanks Gabe Sechan. Indeed proven. I launched for Closed Beta and was able to test only for selected users. The current version in production is not affected.